# Requesting top songs for an artist in Deezer and getting wrong songs (from other artists)

Tags: api, deezer

if I ask for the top 20 songs for the artist "Spazz" e.g.

http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/312485/top?limit=20&output=xml

I get also songs by "Spazz Sparkman" (e.g. Lived and Learned and Got Burned ).

Is this a bug due to the fact that the name of the artists start with the same letters? Any workaround?

The artists actually have two different URLs in deezer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] It is a mistake in the Deezer catalog. We'll fix it asap.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is a catalog mistake.
Don't you get "Lived and Learned and Got Burned" as one of the result? If yes, that song seems by Spazz Sparkman (start from the URL http://www.deezer.com/it/track/8536841 and then GO to the album detail to see it); the weird thing is that sometime I can see "Spazz" (e.g. track detail) and sometime "Spazz Sparkman" (e.g. album details). For sure is not by Spazz (the rapper).